# If element object is in array, don't push the same element object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm adding element objects to an array like this

```
window.elements = [];

var newElement = $(".element");
elements.push( newElement );
```

When an element is clicked, it's added to the array with the code above; If I click the same element twice, the same object will be added again even though the element object is already in the array.

How can check if the element object is already in the array; don't add it.
I tried the following but get -1 even if its in the array.

```
var newElement = $(".element");
if( jQuery.inArray( newElement, elements ) ) {
   elements.push( newElement );
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why it has to be an array? And does your element have an ID or other unique identifier?

Comment: @vol7ron May be OP need a collection and apply something at once later ?

Comment: There's generally no need to keep elements in an array, just add a class on click instead, and select all elements with that class when needed, and there won't be any duplicates, and it works a lot better.

Comment: @ANS maybe maybe not.  The question is why is an Array preferable to an Object. For some pseudo code:  `els={};  els[ <key> ] = el;` will never produce duplicates if your key is unique.  No need to check for existence.  Arrays offer order, but that can also be tracked in the object `els[ <key> ] = { el: el, order: <object.keys.length> }`

Comment: @adeneo for cases where elements are removed from the DOM for efficiency (e.g., large tables) or replaced dynamically (e.g., ajax-select options) it may be necessary to hold onto an element.

Comment: @vol7ron While to true, that is a wild guess. Let see what is in OP mind and what reason pushed him/her to take an array of objects

Comment: I realized that in trying to make it efficient, I made it more complicated. I don't need an array I could use a class.

Comment: @guub I thought you already had a class called `element`

Comment: I used that for the example. It's multiple elements with different classes

Comment: @vol7ron - even if that is the case, you'd use jQuery's `detach()` for that, and still keep the elements in a jQuery collection, not an array.

Comment: I wouldn't use *jQuery* for any of it ;)  Nothing here necessitates the need of jQuery that Vanilla JS doesn't already easily accommodate or provide.

Answer (score 0):

That is because `jQuery.inArray` uses `===` and two individuals objects never be same with `===` cause they point to refer different reference. When you do $ (selector), you always get a new Object. Hence they are two different references pointing to same DOM element.

So what you can do is (*one possible solution*) add an attribute to the object.

On click of the object set a data attribute

```
var newElement = $(".element");
if( ! $(".element").attr("data-arr")) {
   elements.push( newElement );
   $(".element").attr("data-arr", true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Array.Prototype.indexOf()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp) method, which returns `-1` if the specified item is not found in the array:

```
if (elements.indexOf(newElement) === -1 {
  elements.push(newElement);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var newElement = $(".element");
if( !jQuery.inArray( newElement, elements ) ) {
   elements.push( newElement );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`inArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) will return `-1` if there is no match and zero if it is first index in array. So you must compare to `-1` because `0` is falsy

Compare and push  the actual dom element to the array to avoid using different object references.

```
window.elements = [];

$('.someClass').click(function(){
   if( jQuery.inArray( this, elements ) === -1 ) {
      elements.push( this);
   }
})
```

---

Simply adding a class to the element instead would probably be much simpler...then filter out all the clicked ones by that class and let jQuery provide the array needed.

Answer (score 0):

`$(".element")` does not return a single element. It returns an array of all items with `class="element"`. You are trying to add a clicked-on item to the array. Assuming the clickable items have class element, you can do it like this:

```
$('.element').click(function(){
    elements.push($(this));
    return false;
});
```

Comment: where's the duplicate check?